# Building Privacy settings for users

Tags: database, database-design, architecture

How would you design a privacy setting on a per-user basis?

For example, Id like my *email* to be shown only to connections where as my *alias* can be shown to everybody and my *phone number* to be hidden to all.

Im thinking of building this table and joining it onto my users table:

```
--------------------------------------------------
| Column            | Data Type                  |
--------------------------------------------------
| id (primary key)  | uuid                       |
--------------------------------------------------
| user_id           | uuid (with index)          |
--------------------------------------------------
| email_visibility  | enum [none, known, all]    |
--------------------------------------------------
| phone_visibility  | enum [none, known, all]    |
--------------------------------------------------
| alias_visibility  | enum [none, known, all]    |
--------------------------------------------------
```

The caveat to this is the performance. If I want to fetch all users with a route like `/users`, it has now gone from:

```
// Before
SELECT * 
FROM users 
WHERE "I know this person"
```

To a much more complicated

```
// After
SELECT *
FROM users 
JOIN user_privacies
ON users.id = user_privacies.user_id
WHERE "I know this person"

// Delete all the extra data
1. Loop through all the users and scan their privacy setting
2a. If user does not want to show email, delete email
2b. If user does not want to show phone, delete phone
2c. If user does not want to show alias, delete alias
```

This seems like a pretty straight-forward way to build it but I don't think this is a scalable process. Any advice or articles relating to similar architecture would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

As you said it's pretty straight-forward but i think the problem is how you are listing your users.

Usually you list only the data that needs not much processing and keep the process heavy stuff for single item pages. You should think about the fact that how much of the process you are doing is actually necessary and the user will actually use it.

And even if you have to do it this way, then i don't think it is that much of a problem. You can use pagination to simply split your data to little chunks and then i don't think a for loop even for 50 users with 3 ifs would be that much of a problem. Specially if the render is server-side.

You can write more complicated query alongside some codes that optimize the performance but still you should be fine with processing little amount of data at a time.

In general how a database should be designed is highly depended on how your app is going to use the data. You should consider more than just your database to design a good schema.